# How to debug Lua script code?

Tags: lua, garrys-mod

```
local function CreateCvar(cvar, value)
    CreateClientConVar(cvar, value)
end
--cvars
CreateCvar("bunnyhop_test", 0)
CreateCvar("bunnyhop_test_off", 0)

if CLIENT then
    function ReallyHiughJumpoBHOP()
    --concommand.Add("+bhop",function()
    if GetConVarNumber("bunnyhop_test") then
    hook.Add("Think","hook",function()
    RunConsoleCommand(((LocalPlayer():IsOnGround() or LocalPlayer():WaterLevel() > 0) and "+" or "-").."jump")
    end
end)


    function ReallyHiughJumpoBHOPoff()
--concommand.Add("-bhop",function()
    if GetConVarNumber("bunnyhop_test_off") then
    RunConsoleCommand("-jump")
    hook.Remove("Think","hook")
end)
```

This is a lua script made for the game "Garry's mod". What this does is supposed to jump repetitively. I have edited the base code that did work, and now my code no longer works.

Trying to use the createcvars to make it work. I did have it working showing no errors, but in the game when I typed "bunnyhop_test 1" in console it wouldn't work.

Below is original code I started with:

```
if CLIENT then
    concommand.Add("+bhop",function()
        hook.Add("Think","hook",function()
            RunConsoleCommand(((LocalPlayer():IsOnGround() or LocalPlayer():WaterLevel() > 0) and "+" or "-").."jump")
        end)
    end)

    concommand.Add("-bhop",function()
        RunConsoleCommand("-jump")
        hook.Remove("Think","hook")
    end)
end
```

Comment: Yeah I kinda butchered it ^.^

Comment: Ok, i can see that you wanted to change the script with your own console variable. i updated the code so that you can write `bunnyhop_test 1` to enable and `bunnyhop_test 0` to disable the script. You will need to start it up with `+bhop` of course.

Answer (score 1):

You messed up your `end` keyword order. Some `if` statements don't correctly close, and some function declarations do not have a correct closing `end`.

From the edit, i can only guess this is what you wanted to do:

```
local function CreateCvar(cvar, value)
    CreateClientConVar(cvar, value)
end

--cvars
CreateCvar("bunnyhop_test", 0)

if CLIENT then
    concommand.Add("+bhop",function()
            hook.Add("Think","hook",function()
                if GetConVarNumber("bunnyhop_test") == 1 then
                    RunConsoleCommand(((LocalPlayer():IsOnGround() or LocalPlayer():WaterLevel() > 0) and "+" or "-").."jump")
                end
            end)
        end
    end)

    concommand.Add("-bhop",function()
        RunConsoleCommand("-jump")
        hook.Remove("Think","hook")
    end)
end
```

See, when a function is declared inline, referred to as a *closure*, you have to match it with the keyword `end`, to denote its end. Also, note that you are passing in these inline functions as parameters to another function, `.Add`, which starts off with `(` and must finish with `)`. `if` statements, also need to have a `end` keyword to denote the end of the `if`. All of these are basic programming principles, try reading more code to get familiarized with how to write more code, maybe start with the [lua documentation](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/).

I also modified the code so that you can write `bunnyhop_test 0` to disable and `bunnyhop_test 1` to enable the script.

Comment: Thank you I now have no errors. The code does work as intended,BUT what I don't understand is this.    I thought by me adding the convar's I could turn it on/off.  When I go into my console and type " +bhop " It works fine!!! But if I try and turn it on via "bunnyhop_test 1 " It does nothing. And I don't understand that part.

Comment: `GetConVarNumber` will return the value for the value you set it with, **but** since it returns 0, lua will take it as `true`, only `false` or `nil` are false. You will have to check for equality there, like `GetConVarNumber("bunnyhop_test_off") == 1`

Comment: So I would need something like this maybe ?  ------------------------------------if GetConVarNumber("bunnyhop_test") > 0 then

Comment: Yes, `GetConVarNumber("bunnyhop_test_off") == 1` or `GetConVarNumber("bunnyhop_test_off") > 0` would work, unless the returned value is a string.

Comment: Then I guess the return value is a string because it won't turn off with the cmd " bunnyhop_test_off "    the +bhop and -bhop turns it on and off fine.